# Testing if two countries have different GDPs

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

So I have a data set showing a GDP for 50+ countries. I want to see if the difference between two countries are significant. I am thinking I would use a two sided t test because the data is parametric and normally distributed(?). Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It sounds like you have only 2 numbers to compare, so no test is going to be very meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you have only one value for each country (i.e., each country's GDP) and want to check if there is a significant difference between those two values?

If yes, then you can't do a significance test based on that data. And if you think about it - why should you? If you are asking whether the GDPs are different at a specific timepoint, and you already have the exact answer, then you can conclude whether that is true or not simply based on the actual GDP values.

If you instead have a sample of observations (for example GDP-values for the same country over several years, or GDP-values for groups of countries, .e.g., is the average GDP in Asia different from that of South America), and these observations are normally distributed, then you could use a two sided t-test.